# Matlab returns exit code immediately

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess, exit-code

I am creating various matlab .m-files with python and then run them using subprocess. When the files are finished I would like to delete them:

```
    command = ['C:\\MatlabR2012b\\bin\\matlab.exe', '-nodesktop', '-nosplash', '-r', 'mfile']
    matlab = subprocess.Popen(command) # launch matlab with m file
    matlab.wait() # wait for matlab to finish before deleting .m file
    print "delete"
    os.remove(self.filename)
```

The problem is that matlab.wait() never waits, since matlab returns exit code 0 immediately. Is there another way to check if matlab has finished?

Comment: unrelated: you could use `subprocess.check_call(command)` instead of `Popen(..).wait()`. The former also raises an exception if `command` exits with non-zero status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, there is both `bin\matlab.exe` and `bin\win32\matlab.exe` (or `bin\win64\matlab.exe`). The former is just a wrapper around the latter and pretty much exits immediately.

You can either call `bin\win32\matlab.exe` directly or use the [`-wait` option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html) when calling `bin\matlab.exe`.

Comment: You sir, are my eternal hero! :D I would never had found that one.

Comment: @Pphoenix: Glad that I could help you!